# Using a VLookup in VBA to retrieve company name?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm currently designing a macro that auto-populates a table in Excel from a drop-down list. Basically, in one sheet, there is a table of 200 companies. This has a field named **Manager** (for people looking after the company) which contains a drop-down list with all 12 possible managers' names. When I select a manager, it populates the company name to their section of the table.

Only problem is that I'm trying to use a VLookup in VBA to retrieve the company name. So for example, if I select a manager from row 123, I want to assign the company name in column 'C' to the **companyName** variable (which then gets inserted into the auto-populating table.

Here is my VLookup code so far:

```
companyName = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveCell.Address, Sheets("Companies").Range("C8:K208"), 1, False)
```

I've seen a number of different ways to do VLookups and generally I find them quite confusing. Whenever it tries to do the lookup it just says "**Run-time error 1004: Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class**".

Any help on what's going wrong here would be much appreciated. It's been about 6 years since I last looked at Visual Basic in any sort, and I haven't been working with Excel macros that long - so sorry if I'm missing something blindly obvious!

Comment: have you tried putting ActiveCell.value instead of ActiveCell.Address ?

Comment: Yep, sadly that doesn't work either :(

Comment: `ActiveCell` approach is never recommended.. it fraught with danger. Can you share either the full code or relevant code? I suspect that `ActiveCell.Address` might either have an invalid value or empty

Comment: what column holds the managers' names and what column holds the company names?

Answer (score 0):

From VBA: Lookup_value is the value to be found in the first column of the array. Lookup_value can be a value, a **reference**, or a text string.

Referring to the **reference** part which you are obviously trying to use: in VBA a reference is `ActiveCell`, `.range("A5")` or `.cells(1, 2)` NOT the Address like in Excel `A1` or `B7` etc.

```
companyName = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveCell, _
Sheets("Companies").Range("C8:K208"), 1, False)
```

or (at least in my 2003 version)

```
companyName = Application.VLookup(ActiveCell, _
Sheets("Companies").Range("C8:K208"), 1, False)
```

But I still wouldn't play with `ActiveCell`.

Comment: If you look closely at the vlookup, it is trying to lookup in column c and return from column c. You might as well just say `companyName = ActiveCell`. The op is trying to look up a manager and return the company name so I don't think they know how vlookup works.

Comment: The generic condescending Stack Overflow response is ever appreciated user 10735198! Initially I was using a VLookup formula (not code) that used the drop-down list (in column K, not C) and it pulled from the corresponding C column on the row. I was hoping to integrate it into VBA which is why I asked.

Answer (score -1):

My advice is to not use VLookup in VBA. It is slow, though if your table is only ~200 entries large it should be manageable. What I would do is to read the table into a dictionary keyed by the manager name with values of the company name.

There is a VBA-less alternative: change the format of your table from
|Company|Manager|
|:-|:-|
|Company1|Manager1|
Etc.
To
|Company|Manager|Company|
|:-|:-|:-|
|Company1|Manager1|Company1|
Etc.
Now you can just do a cell formula for the VLookup

Comment: I think the question how you do it in VBA so he can add it to his code.